# I accidentally saved an rmarkdown file as .html, is there a way back?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

As the question says, I had opened a new .Rmd file and did all my work in it without saving it. Then when I wanted to knit it to HTML, RStudio prompted me to first save the rmarkdown file. I didn't fully realize and saved it with .HTML as extension instead of .Rmd. Now the file is all screwed up and I cannot find a way back.

Does anyone have a solution for this to recover my work or will I have to do it over again?

Comment: Just saving the file with a different extension should not change its contents. Did you try to open the file with RStudio (or a text editor) and save it *as* a file with extension ".Rmd"?

Comment: Yes i tried, but by saving it as .HTML, RStudio actually completely reformatted the contents and resaving it as .rmd just results in gibberish... Thanks for your suggestions. I suppose I just need to redo the work.